# Mysql INSERT query inserts zeroes

Tags: php, mysql

Hello StackOverflow,

I have following code:

```
 $ref = do_query("SELECT * FROM issues ");
while($issue_info = mysql_fetch_object($ref)) {

$ref0 = do_query("SELECT id, name, day FROM ids WHERE id =  '".$issue_info->region."' ");
$issue_data = mysql_fetch_object($ref0);



$issue = $issue_info->id;
$w = GetInfo($issue_data->id, $issue_data->name, $region_data->day);
do_query("INSERT INTO all (id, location, issue) VALUES ('NULL', location = '$location', issue = '$w') "));

}
```

After do_query(), table 'all' should contain this:

ID: 1 Location: 7 Issue: 66

But instead of this it inserts:
ID: 1 Location: 0 Issue: 0
I'm not sure where my problem is located. $issue returns 7 and $w returns 66

Ah, and i'm sorry for my english :)

Comment: location = '$location' works in update statement... not in insert statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your creating an expression in your `VALUES` field that's causing a final 0 to be inserted. rewrite it without the use of field names

```
do_query("INSERT INTO all (id, location, issue) 
    VALUES ('NULL', '$location', '$w') "));
```

Comment: Thank you!. I don't know why i didn't noticed this.